# Failed Stale Template Cache Delete Error...Analyzed...But No Answer

Tags: templating, cache, craft2

For some of the extremely static content on my site, I use caching to prevent multiple db queries during every single load. I also have multiple locale on my site with custom cache key names. The actual execution of cache is running perfectly at the moment on all the locales.

However, when I make changes to any entry which has cache enabled, I get *stale template delete failed* error. When I take look at the actual MySQL table, I see that the requisite cache row is deleted from the table upon making changes to an entry. So I don't quite understand why this error shows up.

Here is a typical cache directive I used in my templates

```
 {% cache globally using key  "www-features" for 24 hours %}
```

When I look at the runtime logs, I see following error which I am assuming it to be associated with this problem

> 2018/11/03 19:10:42 [error] [application] Encountered an error running task 17 (DeleteStaleTemplateCaches), step 13 of 29: An exception was thrown: 
>   CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'dateCreated' in order clause is ambiguous. 
>   The SQL statement executed was: 
>   SELECT `elements`.`id`, `entries`.`sectionId`, `entries`.`typeId`, `entries`.`authorId`, `entries`.`postDate`, `entries`.`expiryDate`
>   FROM `craft_elements` `elements`
>   JOIN `craft_elements_i18n` `elements_i18n` ON elements_i18n.elementId = elements.id
>   JOIN `craft_content` `content` ON content.elementId = elements.id
>   JOIN `craft_entries` `entries` ON entries.id = elements.id
>   JOIN `craft_sections` `sections` ON sections.id = entries.sectionId
>   LEFT JOIN `craft_structures` `structures` ON structures.id = sections.structureId
>   LEFT JOIN `craft_structureelements` `structureelements` ON (structureelements.structureId = structures.id) AND (structureelements.elementId = entries.id)
>   WHERE ((((elements_i18n.locale = :locale) AND (content.locale = :locale)) AND (elements.archived = 0)) AND (elements_i18n.enabled = 1)) AND (`sections`.`handle` IN ('policies'))
>   GROUP BY `elements`.`id`
>   ORDER BY `dateCreated`. Bound with :locale='en_us'

Looks like you have `dateCreated` field in multiple tables used in the join and the statement is not explicitly defining the identity of the table ???

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the answer to this. Here is the [correct answer.](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17458/failed-task-and-various-errors-in-logs)

Basically change `dateCreated` to `elements.dateCreated` in my template.